# fetch() URL data with Javascript React and display as string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have an api that is called like this :

```
http://localhost:5000/record/gopa
```

and it returns the data in this JSON format

```
{"pid":{
  "ck":"F1965121910:265.522.5788.37",
  "name":"gopa",
  "cID":"MVOE9BW5ZZOC"}
}
```

I want to call this from a React function Details2() that is called from a router like this:

```
import Details2 from "./components/Details2";
const App = () => {
 return (
   <div>
     <Navbar />
     <Routes>
       <Route exact path="/" element={<RecordList />} />
       <Route path="/singlerecord/:id" element={<RecordList1 />} />
       <Route path="/details2/:id" element={<Details2 />} />
     </Routes>
   </div>
 );
};
```

the parameter *:id* needs to be passed to the function *Details2()*
This function is located in file */components/Details2.js* and is being called correctly. 
I have stripped down the Details2.js file to the bare essentials and it contains

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router";

 
export default function Details2() {
 const params = useParams();
  
 let z = fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/${params.id.toString()}`).then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
 let cname = z.pid.name
 return (
   <div>
     <h3>Details2</h3>
     {params.id.toString()}
     
   </div>
 );
}
```

I am trying to access the contents of the data that has been returned by the call for onward processing but I am unable to access it in any variable,like *cname*, that is shown here. No output is available, not even the header.
If I remove the assignment, the program works correctly, displays the HTML that is being returned including the value of *params.id.toString()* that is being correctly passed from the router. 
My simple ask is to be able to access the individual values of the various keys that are being returned from the API. Please help me with the code that is required. 
I have seen this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fetch-data-from-an-api-in-reactjs/) where they do something similar. However in this case they are using a *class* but I could not find a way to pass parameters into a class, as I am doing in the case of the *function* Details2().

Comment: This might help aswell [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked well :-)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
 
export default function Detail52() {
 const params = useParams();
 const [dbdata, setData] = useState('empty52');
 
 useEffect(() => {
   async function getData() {
   const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/${params.id.toString()}`);
   //const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/record/gopa`);
 
     if (!response.ok) {
       const message = `An error occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
       window.alert(message);
       return;
     }
     
     const dbdata = await response.json();
     //dbdata = response.json();
     //window.alert(JSON.stringify(dbdata));
     setData(dbdata);
     //setData('fake data')
   }
   getData();
   return;
 },[dbdata]);
 
 return (
   <div>
     <h3>Detail Information</h3>     
       
       <p>{JSON.stringify(dbdata)}</p>
   </div>
 );
 
}
```